# How can I develop a ETH Mining Software

Tags: mining

**Like the title saids** ，I want to develop a softwore to Mining the ETH by POW, and **get ETH**, how can I develop it, and run it on the **Windows**, and which computter language and Technology should I use, Thanks

Comment: Why would you do it?

Comment: I want to develop it because I want to make a new software to make mining faster and lower price，and I want to make money for my food: )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look up one of the most popular miners [miner code](https://github.com/ethereum-mining/ethminer), its open source so you can take it and make your own miner from it. Click fork button and you will have your of github repo after that click "." button on your keyboard that will open visual studio code in that repo after that you can edit source code change name add things remove things when you are done make a commit and push it. Download it to your pc install ms build tools and build it. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

The scope of for the task of creating a new mining software is too wide, and it is probably worth at least 3-5 books of content. The fact that you ask about this probably means you do not have enough software development expertise for this task. Because the scope of the problem is so wide, it is not meaningful to discuss on this forum, as any useful answer would be several pages long.

Comment: I just want to know the WAY or not the every thing about it

Comment: Learn programming, study Ethereum white paper, write the software. That's all. You are unlikely to mining faster or lower price, because you have clearly no idea what you are asking.

Comment: No Ihave learnt the way to write software and have develop some, and I have read the book of the ETH the low price is mean low price to developer

Comment: Developing a mining software requires at leaset 5-10 years of professional software development experience.

Comment: But if I don't know the way, I can't do any thing